# A newbie in SQL asking about functions

Tags: sql

How can I find data that dont end with letter 'g' without using NOT LIKE function, please help

Comment: Without you having tagged the RDBMS you’re seeking answers for (nor the DDL of your table or the column for which you’re seeking to filter on), this question is not particularly possible to answer completely.

Answer (score 1):

select * from table where right(column, 1) != 'g'

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to do it using "not like," I'll answer that.  The function version provided by @Zoories would be more efficient.
This works at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where CustomerName not like '%g';
```